# How do I stop website from caching? Is it at all possible?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, server

I am making a website that needs to be able to be updated about once a day or so. Whenever I update the htdocs, it doesn't update because the website is cached into the device (which means it can take days sometimes for it to update), is there a way to stop this without server side code? If so then how? If I go into icognito mode it works fine though.

I saw a couple other questions saying to use **`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />`**, but this doesn't seem to quite work.

Sorry if this is a dumb question... I don't do web dev.

I have a website, and I updated it. Now it doesn't update for a while...

Comment: does your server sent *ETag headers*?

Comment: note, using `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">` is [discouraged](https://medium.com/@steelcityamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c#d35a)

Comment: The proper way to do this is to have the server add Cache-Control headers to the outgoing pages. You're going to find it difficult to do this effectively without server-side code.